When using the statue do you have to restart?
So, in Minecraft Dungeons, in the tower, there are blue statues that take back to camp, if you do, when you go back in do you keep all your progress?
Also, when you leave do you keep the stuff that you had before you left the Tower?

Please consider accepting the answer if it solved your problem

Yes, those statues are like a checkpoint that lets you "pause" the run and come back in the future. You keep your progress and your current gears.
The statue becomes available once the floor is cleared, because leaving the Tower from the menu "the hard way" costs you one life.

Here's a source from Reddit:

You can stop and leave any floor by going to the tower by the doors. Then pick back up when you want to continue that floor.


Source? Because on my other question you incorrectly said you spend levels, when it's actually EP. Also I couldn't find anything even on the statue in Minecraft fandom or anywhere else for that matter, and is doesn't matter much anymore cus I died at lvl 28/30 but if still like the source

That's my own experience as a player, I've 100%ed the game months ago (that's why my mistake in the other answer). But I can search for a source
